# Setting an union key type for dynamic objects not working

Tags: typescript

I have an object where I dynamically set a field and a value:

```
type PhoneFields = 'deliveryPhoneNumber' | 'pickupPhoneNumber'


(props: {
 phoneField?: PhoneFields
}) {
  const initialValues = {
    [props.phoneField ?? 'deliveryPhoneNumber']: props.address.phone ?? ''
  }
```

I would like to set the type so that I can use only one of the union types as a value for a key in the dynamic object:

```
type PhoneValues = {
  [x in PhoneFields]: string
}
```

But, if I do that, I get a typescript error:

> Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'PhoneValues': deliveryPhoneNumber, pickupPhoneNumber

How should I do this then?

**Updated**

As suggested in comments changing the key in the mapped type to be optional removed the typescript error.

```
type PhoneValues = {
  [x in PhoneFields]?: string
}
```

But, I am not sure what is the benefit of setting a type like that, since if I write a string that is not one of the options of `PhoneFields` I don't get any Typescript error, so for example:

```
const initialValues = {
  [props.phoneField ??  'xxxx']: props.address.phone ?? ''
}
```

Didn't throw an error.

Comment: Just change your key in your mapped type to be optional `{ [x in PhoneFields]?: string }` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgFgewHYQGIEsIBsAmBnKAXigHIdt0A3CAJxHmQgDkBXAWwCNaSoAfUsOgDGAaxZgGKVp24BYAFAKhyPMCgAzIlAAUYGgjB4AXFADeCqFDCIUGbDgD8JyWky48AGgtQAhjhw0EHjGZt6W1oxOUKo06EgA5h5Q3gC+CikAlEQAfKHylspIqlBx6MDoPlgAapUsQSbm+ZZQANoAHiVIsDau9ngAulExcfGpWo3NrXoGeAB0EbZuOFAODqTkWFS09D3SXDQk-SbThrN+AUFzC9CrpCSp6QpAA

Comment: That helped, but I am not sure what is the point with this since if I write a string that is not one of the options of PhoneFields I don't get any Typescript error, so for example: ```const initialValues = {[props.phoneField ??  'xxxx']: props.address.phone ?? ''}``` didn't throw an error. @JaredSmith

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not initialising the value for `['pickupPhoneNumber']`.

You should set it, say like this:

```
type PhoneFields = 'deliveryPhoneNumber' | 'pickupPhoneNumber'

type PhoneValues = {
  [x in PhoneFields]: string
}

const f = (props: {
  phoneField?: PhoneFields,
  address: {
    phone: string, 
  }
}) => {
  const deliveryPhoneNumber = props.phoneField === 'deliveryPhoneNumber' ? props.address.phone : '';
  const pickupPhoneNumber = props.phoneField === 'pickupPhoneNumber' ? props.address.phone : '';
  const initialValues: PhoneValues = {
    ['deliveryPhoneNumber']: deliveryPhoneNumber,
    ['pickupPhoneNumber']: pickupPhoneNumber
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could change your `PhoneValues` like this:

```
type PhoneValues = {
  [x in PhoneFields]: string | undefined
}
```

So this would work:

```
(props: {
 phoneField?: PhoneFields,
  address: {
    phone: string, 
  }
}) => {
  const initialValues = {
    [props.phoneField ?? 'deliveryPhoneNumber']: props.address.phone ?? ''
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want the type to have either `deliveryPhoneNumber` or `pickupPhoneNumber` (but not both), you could do this:

```
type PhoneFields = 'deliveryPhoneNumber' | 'pickupPhoneNumber';

type PhoneValues = 
  { deliveryPhoneNumber: string, pickupPhoneNumber?: never }
  | { deliveryPhoneNumber?: never, pickupPhoneNumber: string }

const f = (props: {
  phoneField?: PhoneFields,
  address: {
    phone?: string, 
  }
}): PhoneValues => {
  const result: PhoneValues = {
    [props.phoneField ?? 'deliveryPhoneNumber']: props.address.phone ?? ''
  } as unknown as PhoneValues;
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

f({phoneField: 'deliveryPhoneNumber', address: {phone: '123'}});
f({phoneField: 'pickupPhoneNumber', address: {phone: '456'}});
f({address: {phone: '789'}});
f({address: {}});
```

You will notice I'm using double assertion above since Typescript could not infer `{ [key: string]: string }` to be the same as `PhoneValues` even if `key` is of type `PhoneFields`.

If you do not want the double assertion, you could write it like this:

```
type PhoneFields = 'deliveryPhoneNumber' | 'pickupPhoneNumber';

type PhoneValues = 
  { deliveryPhoneNumber: string, pickupPhoneNumber?: never }
  | { deliveryPhoneNumber?: never, pickupPhoneNumber: string }

const f = (props: {
  phoneField?: PhoneFields,
  address: {
    phone?: string, 
  }
}): PhoneValues => {
  let result: PhoneValues;
  switch (props.phoneField)  {
    case 'pickupPhoneNumber':
      result = {
        pickupPhoneNumber: props.address.phone ?? ''
      };
      break;
    default:
      result = {
        deliveryPhoneNumber: props.address.phone ?? ''
      };
      break;
  }
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

f({ phoneField: 'deliveryPhoneNumber', address: { phone: '123'}});
f({ phoneField: 'pickupPhoneNumber', address: { phone: '456'}});
f({ address: { phone: '789'}});
f({ address: {}});
```

Comment: But, I want it to be one of the two values, not both, is there a better way of achieving that then?

Comment: @Ludwig, I updated my answer in response to your question comment